# Async/ await in Firebase Cloud Function says Error Expression has type `void`

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use async/await in my firebase function but I am getting an error. I have marked the function as async but when I try to use await inside of it I get error: Expression has type `void`. Put it on its own line as a statement.

I think this is strange because I think it each await function call is already in its own line as a statement. So, I'm not sure what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

For clarity, I am making a request with the Cheerio web scrape library, and then trying to make two async function calls during each loop with the .each method.

```
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, response) => {


const options = {
uri: 'https://www.cbssports.com/nba/scoreboard/',
transform: function (body) {
    return cheerio.load(body);
}
};

request(options)
.then(($) => {


$('.live-update').each((i, element) => {

        const homeTeamAbbr = $(element).find('tbody').children('tr').eq(0).find('a').html().split("alt/").pop().split('.svg')[0];
        const awayTeamAbbr = $(element).find('tbody').children('tr').eq(1).find('a').html().split("alt/").pop().split('.svg')[0];
        const homeTeam = $(element).find('tbody').children('tr').eq(0).find('a.team').text().trim();
        const awayTeam = $(element).find('tbody').children('tr').eq(1).find('a.team').text().trim();
        let homeTeamStatsURL = $(element).find('tbody').children('tr').eq(0).find('td').html();
        let awayTeamStatsURL = $(element).find('tbody').children('tr').eq(1).find('td').html();
        const gameTime = $(element).find('.pregame-date').text().trim();

        homeTeamStatsURL = homeTeamStatsURL.match(/href="([^"]*)/)[1] + "roster";
        awayTeamStatsURL = awayTeamStatsURL.match(/href="([^"]*)/)[1] + "roster";

        const matchupString = awayTeamAbbr + "@" + homeTeamAbbr;
        const URLString = "NBA_" + urlDate + "_" + matchupString;
        // var docRef = database.collection('NBASchedule').doc("UpcommingSchedule");
        // var boxScoreURL = "www.cbssports.com/nba/gametracker/boxscore/" + URLString;

        // var setAda = docRef.set({[URLString]:{
        //   homeTeam: homeTeam,
        //   awayTeam: awayTeam,
        //   date: gameTime,
        //   homeTeamAbbr: homeTeamAbbr,
        //   awayTeamAbbr: awayTeamAbbr,
        //   homeTeamStatsURL: homeTeamStatsURL,
        //   awayTeamStatsURL: awayTeamStatsURL,
        //   boxScoreURL: boxScoreURL
        // }}, { merge: true });

         getTeamPlayers(homeTeamStatsURL, matchupString);
         getTeamPlayers(awayTeamStatsURL, matchupString);

        console.log("retrieved schedule for "+ matchupString + " on " + urlDate)



});

 response.send("retrieved schedule");
})
.catch(function (err) {
   console.log("error " + err);
});

});
```

The function I am calling just makes another request and then I'm trying to log some data.

```
function getTeamPlayers(playerStatsURL, matchupString) {


const options = {
    uri: playerStatsURL,
    transform: function (body) {
        return cheerio.load(body);
    }
};

 console.log(playerStatsURL + " stats url");

request(options)

.then(($) => {

    console.log('inside cheerio')

     $('tbody').children('tr').each(function(i, element){

        const playerName = $(element).children('td').eq(1).children('span').eq(1).find('a').text().trim();

        const injury = $(element).children('td').eq(1).children('span').eq(1).children('.icon-moon-injury').text().trim();
        const news = $(element).children('td').eq(1).children('span').eq(1).children('.icon-moon-news').text().trim();

        const playerUrl = $(element).children('td').eq(1).children('span').eq(1).find('a').attr('href');
        const playerLogsUrl = "https://www.cbssports.com" + playerUrl.replace('playerpage', 'player/gamelogs/2018');

        console.log(playerName + ": Inj: " + injury + " News: " + news);



        // database.collection('NBAPlayers').add({[playerName]:{
        //   '01 playerName': playerName,
        //   '03 playerLogsUrl': playerLogsUrl,
        //   '04 inj': injury,
        //   '05 news': news

        // }})
      //   .then(docRef => {

      //     console.log("ID " + docRef.id);
      //     //getPlayerLogs(playerLogsUrl, playerName, docRef.id);

      //   })
      //   .catch(error => console.error("Error adding document: ", error));
       });
```

});

}

Comment: are you talking about `client` functions or `server` CloudFunctions?

Comment: server cloud functions

Comment: i haven't seen before the use of `jquery $` inside `nodejs` functions

Comment: In ionic2/3 or angular2/6 this kind of error `Expression has type void` means you have not set properly the type `Promise<any>` to the function which call the API... is this the case do you think?

Comment: jquery $ is only because of the Cheerio web scraping api which has jquery selectors. I'm using typescript on this, and not sure if I am setting the type correctly. I'm going to try refactoring like Ron suggests below.

Comment: Do you mean the function 'getTeamPlayers()' should return type Promise<any> ?

Comment: Wait. I think you are a bit confused about client code and server cloud functions code... typescript is only for client code

Comment: this is an example of async lato client: `private async saveData(formData): Promise<any> { ... }` and this cloud function `exports.helloAsync = async data => { ... } ` looking your code seems client code like my first example. If you want i'll wrie an answer

Comment: I updated my code above to be more complete. I think I'm using typescript for cloud functions - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jr7pDZ1RAUg

Comment: i think you are a little confused

Comment: Yes I am I'm sorry

Comment: It's not important, the important thing is that you've solved

Answer (score 0):

`async/await` is supported in the Node version 8 (which is deployable as Cloud Functions for Firebase).  Specifically, use 8.6.1 (at the time of this writing).

As for awaiting x2 inside a loop - I don't think this is best practice.

Instead, push all these requests into an array, then `Promise.all` so as to fetch all in parallel.

Comment: Thanks Ron, I'm still learning a lot trying to understand promises. I tried pushing both into an array  and then calling Promise.all with the array but I'm still getting the same error. Maybe 'getTeamPlayers()' has to return a promise first?

Comment: But all I want is for getTeamPlayers() to execute and write to the database so I don't know why I need to return anything. I originally wrote this as two basic functions calls and the code works that way but I thought it would be bad practice.

Comment: turn on linting in firebase. it will then warn/alert you to coding issues on deployment. ...Node.js coding takes some getting used to - it's different from client side style.

Answer (score 0):

just in case someone comes after. As Ron stated before, you shouldn't use `async/await` inside a traditional for loop if the second call doesn't need the value of the first, as you will increase the run time of the code.

Furthermore you can't use `async/await` inside of a `forEach=>` or a `map=>` loop, as it won't stop and wait for the promise to resolve.

The most efficient way is to use `Promise.all([])`. Here I leave a great youtube video of a crack that explains `async/await` and Promises => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vn3tm0quoqE&t=6s

As to one of the questions in the comments by DarkHorse:

> But all I want is for getTeamPlayers() to execute and write to the database so I don't know why I need to return anything.

In Firebase Functions all functions need to return something before the final response.

For example in this case, he has created an http function. Before he ends the function with `response.send("retrieved schedule");` you need to finish each and every function triggered. As Firebase Functions will clean up after the final `response`, erasing and stoping anything that it is still running. So any function that hasn't finish will be killed before doing its job.

Returning a promise is the way Firebase Functions knows when all executions have finished and can clean up.

Hop it helps :)